# Iterating Over Object Keys in Freemarker Templates with SuiteScript 2.1 Custom Data Source

Tags: netsuite, datasource, freemarker, suitescript

In my Suitelet script I add custom data source to renderer. In Freemarker Template I am able to access the data. I am also able to list all the arrays of custom data source. Problem is, I cannot seem to be able to iterate over object keys.

Adding custom data source in Suitelet:

```
const obj1 = {
    currency: "EUR Currency",
    transactions: {
        EUR: [
            {
                parent_transaction: "101",
                total: "31.00"
            },
            {
                parent_transaction: "202",
                total: "650.00"
            },
            {
                parent_transaction: "303",
                total: "50.00"
            }
        ],
        USD: [
            {
                parent_transaction: "2",
                total: "32221.00"
            },
            {
                parent_transaction: "3",
                total: "64250.00"
            }
        ]
    }
}

const obj = JSON.stringify(obj1)

renderer.addCustomDataSource( {
    format: render.DataSource.JSON,
    alias: 'obj',
    data: obj
} )
```

Freemarker template:

```
<div>
    <#list obj.transactions?keys as currency>
    <h2>${currency}</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Parent Transaction</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <#list obj.transactions[currency] as transaction>
            <tr>
                <td>${transaction.parent_transaction}</td>
                <td>${transaction.total}</td>
            </tr>
            </#list>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </#list>
</div>
```

Example of the using data source successfully:

```
<p>First EUR transaction's total: ${obj.transactions.EUR[0].total}</p>
```

If I create a similar hash in the template, iterating works fine:

```
<#assign myHash = {"transactions": {"EUR": [{"number": 1}, {"number": 2}, {"number": 3}], "USD": [{"number": 4}, {"number": 5}, {"number": 6}]}}>

<table>
<#list myHash.transactions?keys as key>
<tr>
    <#list myHash.transactions[key] as txn>
    <td>${txn.number}</td>
</#list>
</tr>
</#list>
</table>
```

I also checked that obj.transactions has content before iterating. I have tried both format render.DataSource.OBJECT and render.DataSource.JSON. Why isn't iterating over object keys possible with custom data source?

Comment: Not sure what Java objects they convert that stringified JSON before passing it to FreeMarker. If it was a Java `Map`, then `?key` should work. Anyway, what happens if you try to list the keys? What keys do you see? BTW, ideally you can even do `<#list currency, transactionsOfCurrency as obj.transactions>`.

Comment: I have dynamic number of different possible "currency" keys, so listing them by name is not possible. listing  obj.transactions?key` does not list anything. `obj.transactions?keys?has_content` is not true. `obj.transactions?keys?join(", ")` is empty. Workaround is to add `obj1.currencies = Object.keys(obj1.transactions)` in SuiteScript file and then use that array when listing transactions

Comment: Well, then they use some `ObjectWrapper` that doesn't expose the keys to FreeMarker for that kind of object... whatever that is on Java level (maybe some Jackson or Gson node even, who knows). Then FreeMarker can't do much. It sees what the application wants to expose, and on the way it wants to. And then they provide an `Object.keys(obj)` utility? Weird.

Comment: I use `Object.keys()` in suitescript file (.js) before adding the custom data source. Not in the freemarker template file. Btw, in freemarker template, I checked `obj?is_hash` and it was true. But also when I use `render.addRecord()` and load Vendor or Subsidiary record to the template, they are hashes too in the freemarker template and `?keys` does not work either

Comment: NetSuite uses an old version of Freemarker, 2.3.26 so eval_json is not available and you need to use ?eval to convert the string to object

Comment: Supporting `?keys` is optional for FreeMarker "hash"-es. Only getting items is required from them. And it seems in this case only support that. Maybe even that is accidental on Netsuite's side... If freemarker sees a `get(String)` on a object, it usually exposes the object as a hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
<#assign things = obj.transactions?eval>
<#list things as thing>....
```

Comment: This won't help. Data is already parsed when template receives it.

Comment: I think when you send render.DataSource.JSON it is stringified, you could try render.DataSource.OBJECT

Comment: Hi, this has also been tried and mentioned in the question.